# Get a signal from position array data

Tags: matlab

I'm working with position data from a hand sensor, and need to apply an FFT to it to get the level of tremor based on the frequency of the signal. I get two arrays, one with +1000 frames of position data, the other with +1000 timestamps related to position data, both in .csv files. I'm having trouble formatting the data for the FFT function on matlab. How i transform my position (and probably timestamps) data to a signal who can be processed on function FFT()?

Answer (score 1):

FFT in matab uses a dataset as a vector or an array. If the array is X, the FFT is calculated using FFT(X). Therefore first make an array using the csv file. You can use X = csvread(filename). Then use FFT(X) command. You dont need the time stamp for this.

Comment: fft does assume that each time steps is of the same size. So one would have to check this.

Comment: Thank you for replying! I have a doubt about that, my sampling frequency is not static, it varies by 3-6% for each frame. That's why I rescued the time stamps assuming they would be necessary for the FFT, how can be implemented to the calculation my time matrix to give more robustness to the result?

Comment: Doesn’t the number of data points in an FFT have to be a power of 2?

Comment: Since the difference of the sampling time is about 5%, you can interpolate the values and make a uniformly sampled dataset. Use 'resample' function available in the matlab. Let me know if you need further help.